# Concat after autoincremented

Tags: mysql

I have a table `member` with below fields.

```
number
id_number
name
gender
```

Field `number` is on auto-increment.

I want to join number and gender field into the id_number field.

E.g. Gender is `M` & number is `001` then id_number will be `M001`.

I've tried to combine those two fields, but the number field always joined before the number incremented (M000, M000, W000).

Please help me & thanks in advance...

Comment: when do you wnt to concat? while inserting record or selecting records?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by combining 2 fields? I cannot come with a good scenario where someone has to do that. You can always combine them when doing select.

Comment: mysql by default increments auto_increment to 1 + max(auto_increment).

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **Don't do this** - concat on `SELECT`, not on `INSERT`

If you REALLY have a business logic case, that needs that, you wil want a trigger `AFTER INSERT` on that table (and if the gender can change, then also `AFTER UPDATE`) to create the concatenation - in the "AFTER" triggers the `AUTO_INCREMENT` field is populated.

Comment: sorry, but can u give me some example, cos I'm still beginner

Comment: how to populated the auto_increment before concatenation?